# Enabling/Disabling MGWT Button

Tags: gwt, button, mgwt

I'm beginner to GWT and MGWT. In my project I've a requirement that I have to enable
and disable the MGWT Botton. direct method is not given in current version of MGWT.
I've seen it in GWT button.

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button b = new com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button();
b.setEnable(boolean);
```

But it is not given in MGWT.
Please help me,How can we achieve above functionality using CSS/something else

Answer (score 0):

I am not a MGWT guy. And there must be some better solution. You can try low level element manipulation:

```java
Button mgwtButton;
mgwtButton.getElement().setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

If you take this solution it will be better to prepare later your `CustomButton` that extends MGWT Button with additional `setEnabled(boolean enabled)` method to have better API.

Comment: the above is working only for GWT button .I tried it for MGWT button, but it is not working

Comment: It's true, MGWT button is a plain div, not input, sot you need to do some CSS adjustements and then disable corresponding click action...